# Python: remove double quotes from JSON dumps

Tags: python, json

I have a database which returns the rows as lists in following format:

```
data = ['(1000,"test value",0,0.00,0,0)', '(1001,"Another test value",0,0.00,0,0)']
```

After that, I use `json_str = json.dumps(data)` to get a JSON string. After applying `json.dumps()`, I get the following output:

```
json_str = ["(1000,\"test value\",0,0.00,0,0)", "(1001,\"Another test value\",0,0.00,0,0)"]
```

However, I need the JSON string in the following format:

```
json_str = [(1000,\"test value\",0,0.00,0,0), (1001,\"Another test value\",0,0.00,0,0)]
```

So basically, I want to remove the surrounding double quotes. I tried to accomplish this with `json_str = json_str.strip('"')` but this doesn't work. Then, I tried `json_str = json_str.replace('"', '')` but this also removes the escaped quotes.

Does anybody know a way to accomplish this or is there a function in Python similiar to `json.dumps()` which produces the same result, but without the surrounding double quotes?

Comment: Just dump that all that as dictionary rather than string.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242262/dump-to-json-adds-additional-double-quotes-and-escaping-of-quotes

Comment: Just dump the data as a dictionary rather than string value
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242262/dump-to-json-adds-additional-double-quotes-and-escaping-of-quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dumping list of strings so json.dumps does exactly what you are asking for. Rather ugly solution for your problem could be something like below.

```
def split_and_convert(s):
    bits = s[1:-1].split(',')
    return (
        int(bits[0]), bits[1], float(bits[2]),
        float(bits[3]), float(bits[4]), float(bits[5])
    )

data_to_dump = [split_and_convert(s) for s in data]
json.dumps(data_to_dump)
```