# Dump to JSON adds additional double quotes and escaping of quotes

Tags: python, json

I am retrieving Twitter data with a Python tool and dump these in JSON format to my disk. I noticed an unintended escaping of the entire data-string for a tweet being enclosed in double quotes. Furthermore, all double quotes of the actual JSON formatting are escaped with a backslash.

They look like this:

> "{\"created_at\":\"Fri Aug 08 11:04:40 +0000
>   2014\",\"id\":497699913925292032,

How do I avoid that? It should be:

> {"created_at":"Fri Aug 08 11:04:40 +0000 2014" .....

My file-out code looks like this:

```
with io.open('data'+self.timestamp+'.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(unicode(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)))
            f.write(unicode('\n'))
```

The unintended escaping causes problems when reading in the JSON file in a later processing step.

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You are double encoding your JSON strings. `data` is **already** a JSON string, and doesn't need to be encoded *again*:

```
>>> import json
>>> not_encoded = {"created_at":"Fri Aug 08 11:04:40 +0000 2014"}
>>> encoded_data = json.dumps(not_encoded)
>>> print encoded_data
{"created_at": "Fri Aug 08 11:04:40 +0000 2014"}
>>> double_encode = json.dumps(encoded_data)
>>> print double_encode
"{\"created_at\": \"Fri Aug 08 11:04:40 +0000 2014\"}"
```

Just write these directly to your file:

```
with open('data{}.txt'.format(self.timestamp), 'a') as f:
    f.write(data + '\n')
```

Comment: f.write(data + '\n')  -- correlates to -- data = encoded_data  -- from your example.

Comment: @RichElswick the OP uses the variable `data`, which contains already-encoded JSON data, so yes, I used the variable name `encoded_data` to illustrate what was going on.

Comment: For those, like me, who were getting `\\"` when double-escaping, this is because a bare variable like `double_encode` in the interpreter will escape the backslashes for you. If you instead use `print(double_encode)`, as Martijn used, the double-escaped string will be printed with single backslashes as shown.

Answer (score 15):

Another situation where this unwanted escaping can happen is if you try to use json.dump() on the pre-processed output of json.dumps().  For example

```
import json, sys
json.dump({"foo": json.dumps([{"bar": 1}, {"baz": 2}])},sys.stdout)
```

will result in

```
{"foo": "[{\"bar\": 1}, {\"baz\": 2}]"}
```

To avoid this, you need to pass dictionaries rather than the output of json.dumps(), e.g.

```
json.dump({"foo": [{"bar": 1}, {"baz": 2}]},sys.stdout)
```

which outputs the desired

```
{"foo": [{"bar": 1}, {"baz": 2}]}
```

(Why would you pre-process the inner list with json.dumps(), you ask?  Well, I had another function that was creating that inner list out of other stuff, and I thought it would make sense to return a json object from that function... Wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

Extending for others having similar issue, I used this to dump the JSON formatted data to file where the data came from an API call. Just an indicative example below, update as per your requirement

```
import json

# below is an example, this came for me from an API call
json_string = '{"address":{"city":"NY", "country":"USA"}}'

# dump the JSON data into file ( dont use json.dump as explained in other answers )
with open('direct_json.json','w') as direct_json:    
    direct_json.write(json_string)
    direct_json.write("\n")

# load as dict
json_dict = json.loads(json_string)

# pretty print
print(json.dumps(json_dict, indent = 1)) 

# write pretty JSON to file
with open('formatted.json','w') as formatted_file: 
    json.dump(json_dict, formatted_file, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set escape_forward_slashes=False to prevent escaping / characters

Solved:

> `ujson.dumps({"a":"aa//a/dfdf"}, escape_forward_slashes=False  )`
>
> > `'{"a":"aa//a/dfdf"}'`

Default:

> `ujson.dumps({"a":"aa//a/dfdf"}, escape_forward_slashes=True  )`
>
> > `'{"a":"aa\\/\\/a\\/dfdf"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to get around that, which worked for me is to use the json loads function before dumping, like the following :

```py
import json
data = json.loads('{"foo": json.dumps([{"bar": 1}, {"baz": 2}])}')
with open('output.json','w') as f:
   json.dump(data,f,indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue but it was in the db section
like when i add the data from python code to db using json.dump it create the similar like this:
"{"created_at":"Fri Aug 08 11:04:40 +0000 2014","id":497699913925292032,

but instead of using

```
json.dump(existing_dict)
```

use this

```
from sqlalchemy import JSON, cast
existing_dict = cast(existing_dict , JSON)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might have some text data in your json, which is already escaped. Therefore you could use the codecs encode/decode methods to unescape, so you can still use json.dumps.

```py
import json
from codecs import encode, decode

data = { "foo": r'This is an \"example\"' } # -> This is an \"example\"

print(json.dumps(data)) # BAD: -> {"foo": "This is an \\\"example\\\""}

data["foo"] = decode(encode(data["foo"], 'latin-1', 'backslashreplace'), 'unicode-escape')
print(json.dumps(data)) # GOOD: -> {"foo": "This is an \"example\""}
```