# How to send utf8-encoded json string by tcp in Python?

Tags: python, json, unicode, tcp

I'm desesperately trying to send over tcp (Python 2.7) a json string that is utf8-encoded. Here are a few tries and the results. The variable reponse contains the json string I'm trying to send:

```
reponse = {"candidats":{"P":[{"mentionname":"Beyoncé","guess":[{"name":"BEYONCÉ","score":"1.00","eid":"72437"}]}],"E":[]}}
```

The command 1:

```
self.request.sendall(json.dumps(reponse+"\n",ensure_ascii=False))
```

results in error:

```
    'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The command 2:

```
self.request.sendall(json.dumps(reponse+"\n",encoding='utf8')):
```

gives an output at the other end (tcp client) but last character of Beyoncé is not the good one :

```
   "{\"candidats\":{\"P\"[{\"mentionname\":\"Beyonc\u00e9\",\"guess\":[{\"name\":\"BEYONC\u00c9\",\"score\":\"1.00\",\"eid\":\"72437\"}]}],\"E\":[]}}\n"
```

(message is received in the client with message.decode('UTF-8')).

The command 3:

```
self.request.sendall(json.dumps(reponse+"\n",ensure_ascii=False,encoding='utf8')):
```

results in error:

```
    'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The command 4:

```
self.request.sendall(json.dumps(reponse+"\n").encode('utf8')):
```

gives an output at the other end (tcp client) but last character of Beyoncé is not the good one:

```
    "{\"candidats\":{\"P\":[{\"mentionname\":\"Beyonc\u00e9\",\"guess\":[{\"name\":\"BEYONC\u00c9\",\"score\":\"1.00\",\"eid\":\"72437\"}]}],\"E\":[]}}\n"
```

The command 5:

```
self.request.sendall(json.dumps(reponse+"\n",ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')):
```

gives an output at the other end, last character of Beyoncé is the good one but double quote are escaped:

```
    "{\"candidats\":{\"P\":[{\"mentionname\":\"Beyoncé\",\"guess\":{\"name\":\"BEYONCÉ\",\"score\":\"1.00\",\"eid\":\"72437\"}]}],\"E\":[]}}\n"
```

Last try is almost the good one, except for those annoying escaped double quotes. I know that this is because string is [double encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242262/python-dump-to-json-adds-additional-double-quotes-and-escaping-of-quotes) but I have no other choice for the moment to choose this solution and eliminate backslashes in my tcp client code.

Does anybody have a better solution? 
Any hint is greatly appreciated!
Regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are putting the text into the `response` variable in the source, they setting the source file encoding so that the first two lines in the source file reads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

More info can be found in [PEP 0263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: Thanks Donovan but could you explain in more details your answer, I don't understand it.

Comment: If you meant removing the first 2 lines (the source file encoding), it does not change anything to the results. But maybe that's not what you meant.

Comment: I meant adding the `coding: utf8` piece, since the string is in the source file. Did the setting not work?

Comment: The <code>coding:utf8</code> piece was already there. I thought you were saying to remove it.