# How to convert bytes containing a string of a list into a Python object?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have a bytes object `bytes_start` containing a string of a list and I want to turn it into a Python object.

```
bytes_start = b'"[{\\"method\\": \\"NULLABLE\\", \\"title\\": \\"Customer\\", \\"type\\": \\"STRING\\"}, {\\"method\\": \\"NULLABLE\\", \\"title\\": \\"Vendor\\", \\"type\\": \\"INTEGER\\"}]"'
```

I tried using `new_bytes_start = json.dumps(bytes_start)`, but that did not work. How can I use Python 3 to get the following result?

```
new_bytes_start = [{"method": "NULLABLE", "title": "Customer", "type": "INTEGER"}, {"method": "NULLABLE", "title": "Vendor", "type": "FLOAT"}]
```

Comment: You have JSON. Did you mean to *load* it instead? `json.loads(bytes_start)`.

Comment: However, you seem to have encoded it *twice*.  So it'll be `json.loads(json.loads(bytes_start))`. How did you end up with that value in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

Your bytes value contains a [*double-encoded*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242262/dump-to-json-adds-additional-double-quotes-and-escaping-of-quotes/25242376#25242376) JSON document. You don't need to encode this a third time.

If you wanted to *load* the data into a Python object, you need to decode the JSON, *twice*, using [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

new_bytes_start = json.loads(json.loads(bytes_start))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> bytes_start = b'"[{\\"method\\": \\"NULLABLE\\", \\"title\\": \\"Customer\\", \\"type\\": \\"STRING\\"}, {\\"method\\": \\"NULLABLE\\", \\"title\\": \\"Vendor\\", \\"type\\": \\"INTEGER\\"}]"'
>>> json.loads(bytes_start)
'[{"method": "NULLABLE", "title": "Customer", "type": "STRING"}, {"method": "NULLABLE", "title": "Vendor", "type": "INTEGER"}]'
>>> json.loads(json.loads(bytes_start))
[{'method': 'NULLABLE', 'title': 'Customer', 'type': 'STRING'}, {'method': 'NULLABLE', 'title': 'Vendor', 'type': 'INTEGER'}]
```

If you are using a Python version older than Python 3.6, you'll also have to decode the bytestring first; presumably it's UTF-8 at which point you'd use:

```
new_bytes_start = json.loads(json.loads(bytes_start.decode('utf8')))
```