# Writing list of objects to JSON file

Tags: python, json

As part of my homework I have to make a JSON file with class objects in it. I could do it, but the result is not that i expected.

```
import json    
stList = []


class Student(object):
    neptun_code = ""
    result = 0
    mark = 0


def make_student(neptun_code, result, mark):
    student = Student()
    student.neptun_code = neptun_code
    student.result = result
    student.mark = mark

    stList.append(student)


def create_json():
    json_string = json.dumps([ob.__dict__ for ob in stList])
    with open("./data/student.txt", "w") as file:
        json.dump(json_string, file)
```

Sample inputs for `make_student` : *test_code, test_result, test_mark*

Here is the output in student.txt:

```
 "[{\"neptun_code\": \"test_code\", \"result\": \"test_result\", \"mark\": \"test_mark\"}]"
```

there are plenty of unwanted characters in it. **I would like to have something like this:**

```
[{"neptun_code": "test_code", "result": "test_result", "mark": "test_mark"}]
```

Can anyone explain how to do this?

Comment: `json.dump` is designed to take the Python objects, not the already-JSONified string. Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html.

Comment: Similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242262/dump-to-json-adds-additional-double-quotes-and-escaping-of-quotes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use *either* `dumps`, or `dump`.  **Not both.**

`dump` (my preference):

```
def create_json():
    with open("./data/student.txt", "w") as file:
        json.dump([ob.__dict__ for ob in stList], file)
```

**OR** `dumps`:

```
def create_json():
    json_string = json.dumps([ob.__dict__ for ob in stList])
    with open("./data/student.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(json_string)
```

As a side note, in the future you'll want to watch out for [scoping](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) as you're using the global object `stList`.

Answer (score 1):

You are encoding your dictionary to JSON string twice. First you do this here:

```
json_string = json.dumps([ob.__dict__ for ob in stList])
```

and then once again, here:

```
json.dump(json_string, file)
```

Alter this line with `file.write(json_string)`