# Json saving python

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

When I want to save my JSON it adds backslashes and double quotes to it.
So the single quote around is getting replaced with double quotes and it adds the slashes

```js
'{"created_at":"foo","created_by":"foo"}'
```

So when I open the saved file it looks like this

```
"{\"created_at\":\"foo\",\"created_by\":\"foo\"}"
```

and i need to have it like this

```
{"created_at":"foo","created_by":"foo"}
```

My code looks like this:
For saving

```
with open('data3.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data3, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25242376/17079464) post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dump to JSON adds additional double quotes and escaping of quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242262/dump-to-json-adds-additional-double-quotes-and-escaping-of-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Saving with the following code:

```
import json 
test = {"created_at":"foo","created_by":"foo"}
with open('data3.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
json.dump(test, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I get the following:
`{"created_at": "foo", "created_by": "foo"}`

try editing your notepad++ setting maybe something about their display.

Comment: maybe it's important to mention that the json looks like this befor saving it

'{"created_at":"foo","created_by":"foo"}', so there is this single quote around it

Comment: you should maybe convert it to dict type or use json loads before writing to file.