# How to dump json without quotes in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Here is how I dump a file

```
with open('es_hosts.json', 'w') as fp:
  json.dump(','.join(host_list.keys()), fp)
```

The results is

```
 "a,b,c"
```

I would like:

```
 a,b,c
```

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think the output you want is valid JSON? Why do you need it without the quotes?

Comment: I know...but part of a corner case where I dont need the quotes in the output

Comment: @MartijnPieters The OP did not suggest the unquoted string would be used directly as JSON. I had a similar situation recently, where the double quotes are added lateron in the process, so I needed the unquoted but JSON-escaped string.

Comment: @AndreasMaier: that's a completely different situation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thinking about this again, your question seems more appropriate now. Writing a file with extension '.json' seems to indicate that.

Comment: If you want to read a json file and dump part of it to disk (i.e.: save it without the saved file being json), then using `write` may make more sense than using `dump`, e.g. `fp.write(mydata)`.

Answer (score 20):

Before doing a string replace, you might want to `strip` the quotation marks:

```
print '"a,b,c"'.strip('"')
```

Output:

```
a,b,c
```

That's closer to what you want to achieve. Even just removing the first and the last character works: `'"a,b,c"'[1:-1]`.

But have you looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18648125/3419103)?

Comment: This solution is better than the one that suggests to replace all double quotes, but it still removes too much when the last character of the (unquoted) string is an (escaped) double quote, as in `"my name is \"Andy\""`. What you want is to remove exactly only the leading double quote and the trailing double quote.

Comment: I should add that my comment applies to the first solution suggested in the answer (using `strip()`). The second solution (using slicing) works for all cases (and would have deserved its own answer so it can be voted up). Still voting this answer up.

Answer (score 9):

To remove the quotation marks in the *keys* only, which may be important if you are parsing it later (presumably with some tolerant parser or maybe you just pipe it directly into `node` for bizarre reasons), you could try the following regex.

```
re.sub(r'(?<!: )"(\S*?)"', '\\1', json_string)
```

One issue is that this regex expects fields to be seperated `key: value` and it will fail for `key:value`. You could make it work for the latter with a minor change, but similarly it won't work for variable amounts of whitespace after `:`

There may be other edge cases but it will work with outputs of `json.dumps`, however the results will not be parseable by json. Some more tolerant parsers like `yaml` might be able to read the results.

```
import re
regex = r'(?<!: )"(\S*?)"'
o = {"noquotes" : 127, "put quotes here" : "and here", "but_not" : "there"}
s = json.dumps(o)
s2 = json.dumps(o, indent=3)
strip_s = re.sub(regex,'\\1',s)
strip_s2 = re.sub(regex,'\\1',s2)

print(strip_s)
print(strip_s2)

assert(json.loads(strip_s) == json.loads(s) == json.loads(strip_s2) == json.loads(s2) == object)
```

Will raise a `ValueError` but prints what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use python's built-in string replace function

```
with open('es_hosts.json', 'w') as fp:
   json.dump(','.join(host_list.keys()).replace('\"',''), fp)
```

Comment: This solution removes double quotes in the string as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not valid json, so the `json` module won't help you to write that data. But you can do this:

```
import json

with open('es_hosts.json', 'w') as fp:
    data = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    fp.write(json.dumps(','.join(data)).replace('"', ''))
```

That's because you asked for `json`, but since that's not json, this should suffice:

```
with open('es_hosts.json', 'w') as fp:
    data = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    fp.write(','.join(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use for loop to assign list to string.

```py
import json

with open('json_file') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    for value_wo_bracket in data['key_name']:
        print(value_wo_bracket)
```

Note there is difference between `json.load` and `json.loads`