# write into a js file without passing in string quotes (in Python)

Tags: python, json, string

I am writing a parser to grab data from GitHub api, and I would like to output the file into the following .js format:

```
//Ideal output
var LIST_DATA = [
{
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "category"
}]
```

Though I am having trouble writing into `output.js` file with the variable `var LIST_DATA`, no matter what I do with the string, the end result shows as `"var LIST_DATA"`

For example:

```
//Current Output
"var LIST_DATA = "[
{
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "category"
}]
```

My Python script:

```
var = "var LIST_DATA = "
with open('list_data.js', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write(json.dumps(var, sort_keys = True))
```

I also tried using `strip` method according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611882/how-to-dump-json-without-quotes-in-python) StackOverflow answer and got the same result

```
var = "var LIST_DATA = "
with open('list_data.js', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.write(json.dumps(var.strip('"'), sort_keys = True))
```

I am assuming, whenever I am dumping the text into the js file, the string gets passed in along with the double quote... Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `json.dumps` when you write the `var LIST_DATA = `, it is interpreted as a JSON value and so gets wrapped in quotes.

Comment: `var LIST_DATA = [...` is not valid JSON, so `json.dumps` will never output it. What you need is to `outfile.write('var LIST_DATA = '); json.dump(whatever_proper_data, outfile, indent=1)`.

Comment: Thanks so much guys, wow... Of course, now it makes sense: json = quote....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var = '''var LIST_DATA = [
{
    name: "Python",
    type: "category"
}]'''
with open("list_data.js", "w") as f:
    f.write(var)
```

The json library is not what you are looking for here.

And also, dictionaries in Javascript do not require quoted keys unless there are spaces in the key.

Output:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a string to `json.dumps` it will always be quoted. The first part (the name of the variable) is not JSON - so you want to just write it verbatim, and then write the object using `json.dumps`:

```
var = "var LIST_DATA = "
my_dict = [
  {
    "name": "Python",
    "type": "category"
  }
]
with open('list_data.js', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(var)
    # Write the JSON value here
    outfile.write(json.dumps(my_dict))
```